# Error installing XML::DOM::XPath

Tags: xml, linux, xpath, bioperl, activestate

I've written a small Perl script that uses the Bio::Seq and Bio::SeqIO packages. When I try to run the script on a linux-based server. I got a lot of errors which basically told me that BioPerl hadn't been installed.

I installed ActiveState Perl 5.26 locally and have taken care of most of the prerequisites in order to install Bio::Perl. Only XML::DOM::XPath remains a problem. After trying to install the package, I received the following error:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/test_non_ascii.t                  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 10 tests but ran 0.
Files=35, Tests=183,  4 wallclock secs ( 0.12 usr  0.04 sys +  3.46 cusr  0.52 csys =  4.14 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/35 test programs. 0/183 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  MIROD/XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports MIROD/XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz
Failed during this command:
 MIROD/XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz              : make_test NO


nolock_cpan> reports MIROD/XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz
Distribution: M/MI/MIROD/XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz
Fetching 'http://www.cpantesters.org/show/XML-DOM-XPath.yaml'...DONE

Catching error: "CPAN::Exception::yaml_process_error=HASH(0x4ca5c28)" at /data/calvin/ActivePerl-5.26/lib/CPAN.pm line 392.
        CPAN::shell() called at -e line 1
```

This error seems to be connected to t/test_non_ascii.t, as an earlier output of trying to run the command install "XML::DOM::XPath" gave the following error:

```
t/test_non_ascii.t .................... The encoding pragma is no longer supported. Check cperl at t/test_non_ascii.t line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/test_non_ascii.t line 10.
  Looks like your test exited with 2 before it could output anything.
t/test_non_ascii.t .................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 10/10 subtests
```

Does anybody know what the exact cause of the error is and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you ended up figuring this out, but the issue is with the encoding on line 10 of `t/test_non_ascii.t`, which uses `encoding.pm` which is no longer supported after Perl 5.25.3:

```
use encoding 'utf8';
```

[The solution as can be found in the bug reports on CPAN](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=115098) is to change the line to

```
use utf8;
```

Results of `git diff t/test_nonascii.t t/test_non_ascii.t.new`:

```
--- t/test_non_ascii.t
+++ t/test_non_ascii.t.new
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@ use strict;
 use Test::More tests => 10;
 use XML::DOM::XPath;

-use encoding 'utf8';
+use utf8;

 my $display_warning=0;
```

Comment: Could you please describe how to find that test file to edit it?

Comment: the module should have been downloaded somewhere on your system. it should have the same directory structure as on [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/source/MIROD/XML-DOM-XPath-0.14).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Fails exactly the same after changing that line.

Comment: Worked for me! :P

Comment: One should fix up the source archive (not the build directory) and then update the CHECKSUMS file

Answer (score 2):

Although most of the answers above are right, they do not address the problem properly.

Assuming that you are in a Linux system you need to go to the source file which is compressed. You can usually find this at `/home/username/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MI/MIROD/XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz`.
You must uncompress the file

```
tar -xvzf XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz
nano XML-DOM-XPath-0.14/t/test_non_ascii.t
```

Modify the file by substituting `use encoding 'utf8';` with 
`use utf8;`

Save the file with `Ctrl+X` + `S` + `Enter`

Now you must compress the file again using

```
tar -czvf XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz XML-DOM-XPath-0.14/
```

Retrieve `md5` and `sha256sum` as follows:

```
sha256sum XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz
md5sum XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz
```

Replace those checksums in the `CHECKSUMS` file by searching in the json file the filename `XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz`

Now run the installation normally, it should work!

You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but this is the lines I've used:

```
sudo cpanm Bio::Perl
sudo apt install clustalw
sudo cpanm Bio::Tools::Run::Alignment::Clustalw
```

I'm not sure how it works, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

I was using cpanm to install the XML::DOM::XPath and encountered the same error.

To fix this issue, you should modify the "test_non_ascii.t" file (e.g. the path of mine is "/Users/USER_NAME/.cpanm/work/1565320320.17142/XML-DOM-XPath-0.14/t") - change `use encoding 'utf8';` to `use utf8;`, and then install the module using this modified file (see below for my command). It worked well.

```
cpanm /Users/USER_NAME/.cpanm/work/1565320320.17142/XML-DOM-XPath-0.14
```

Comment: I had the same issue, I updated my test_nonascii.t file, and then I tried to install it using - cpanm "/path/XML-DOM-XPath-0.14/" but I was not able to install it. Any other suggestion?

Comment: editing in the source file as suggested by answers below didn't work but editing in the build file and building from there did. any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Andresito's explanation worked for me.  Here are the steps again, but using CPAN::Checksums.

1. cd .cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MI/MIROD
2. tar zxvf XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz
3. edit and save XML-DOM-XPath-0.14/t/test_non_ascii.t
4. tar zcvf XML-DOM-XPath-0.14.tar.gz  XML-DOM-XPath-0.14
5. perl -we 'use CPAN::Checksums qw(updatedir); printf "%s\n", updatedir(".")'
6. cpan cpan XML::DOM::XPath

---